# Is possible to install minifilter drivers on Windows 10 without any certificates?

Tags: windows, windows-10, kernel, driver

I am developing a Mini Filter Driver for a Ransomware Detection college work. The purpose of it is live testing against malwares, not gonna be sold or anything like that. Considering Drivers needs certificates to run on Windows 10, is there a way where I can install the driver anyways despite not having any certficate ?

Comment: the internet has lots of tutorials that deal with installing unsigned drivers on Win 10

Comment: Test signing mode (disables DRM)